# Python IDLE crashed when saving and all my code disappeared

Tags: python-3.x, crash, python-idle

I was writing my code, then I pressed Ctrl+S. It then started not responding. I closed it and came back on to find the file was now empty!

Anyone know how I can retrieve it?

Comment: If it didn't save, it didn't save. You should be saving constantly, or using an IDE that auto saves.

Comment: I believe that this is the first report I have seen of this exact nature.  When you run IDLE again, start it from the console with `python -m idlelib`.  Try typing some random chars and try to save.  If the problem repeats, there might be an error message from IDLE or Python.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's not that I don't save. I'd been working on the code for weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just retyped my code. Luckily, I'd done a backup the previous night, so didn't lose too much.

I am now making sure to do daily backups.